How do i open chrome's memory saver using chromedriver in VBA
Chrome has a new memory saver feature, which I tried to turn on using the Chrome Driver to control Google's browser, but couldn't find. What should I do? I'm using VBA
I can interact with setting as this:
driver.Get ("chrome://settings/")
driver.ExecuteScript ("chrome.settingsPrivate.setDefaultZoom(0.75);")

And i tried
driver.Get ("chrome://settings/?search=memory+saver")

this opens the rgt page i settings, but i cant toggle the memory saver button
i tried this, but no luck, where do i find the right names?
driver.ExecuteScript ("chrome.settingsPrivate.Memorysaver (toggle);")

